# Is posting with query in string allowed in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

for example, calling

```
GET /users/1/items/2?foo=bar
```

calls show(conn, params) and "foo" => "bar" is in my params

what's the equivalent for the post?

```
POST /users/1/items/2?foo=bar
```

It does not hit my update function. Instead I see:

> ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for POST /users/1/items/2 (MyApp.Router)

edit: additional information

```
#routes
resources "/users", UserController do
  resources "/items", ItemController
end

#the template code calling it
<%= user_item_path(@conn, :update, @user, @item, %{"foo" => "bar"}) %>
#I've also tried the post string above
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file? Have you declared a POST route for that URL? or did you mean to do a PUT request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resources` defines a `PUT` and `PATCH` route for the `update` action. If you change the `POST` method in your request to `PUT` or `PATCH`, you should get `"foo" => "bar"` in the params in your action.